# Gtk treeview selection selects and return

Tags: python, treeview, gtk

Why does gtk treeview selection return to the first item whenever i set the cursor. That is when  i run this block of code it works but still returns the cursor to the  first item

```py
path = self.treeview.get_cursor()[0]
path.next()
self.treeview.set_cursor(path)
```

it works and fails without any error.

Thanks.

Comment: sorry for inconsistent gramar

Answer (score 0):

The cursor for the treeview and the cursor for the treeview-selection is separate. You should probably be changing the cursor for the treeview-selection.

Edit:
The functions for the TreeSelection are [select_path](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeSelection.html#gtk-tree-selection-select-path) and [select_iter](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeSelection.html#gtk-tree-selection-select-iter).

Comment: How treeview selection  has no set cursor  function